# correct use of throughput controller (JMeter)

Tags: api, controller, jmeter, throughput

I have the following scenario:

[image]

1. Main thread is set to 50 concurrent users (looping - as testduration will be scheduled).
2. Throughput controllers for all API calls is set to 100% 'Percent Executions' with 'Per User' ticked off.

Except for /pdfbill (set to 50%), as we only want 25 concurrent users here instead of 50 users.

Q: Is this approach correct? Or should i use the 'Per user' option inside the throughput controller for all calls ?

Comment: A possible simplification: if something is supposed to run 100% of the time, it doesn't really need a throughput controller: you can have all "API calls" right under Random Order Controller, except for those you want to run less than 100% of the time. The only reason to keep them, is if in the future you are planning a different breakdown, or if they include more than one sampler (you could use Simple Controller too in this case)

Comment: Didn't look at it this way.. Thanks. My main goal in this scenario was letting /pdfbill only utilize half of my global concurrent users (+/- 25 of 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your approach is correct as er this documentation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller